# How do I store dynamic data and bind it to a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, dynamicobject

I've been at this for a few days, and I can't seem to find the correct approach to bind dynamic data to a DataGridView.

I'm downloading data from a web API that is delivered in JSON. Newtonsoft JSON deserializes the data and stores it in a dynamic. I can bind this to my DataGridView with no problems. I can even add members to it.

```
public partial class frmTBAstatistics : Form
{
    private static frmTBAstatistics _instance;
    public static frmTBAstatistics GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new frmTBAstatistics();
        return _instance;
    }

    //private dynamic matches;
    private dynamic matches;
    private dynamic teamstats = new BindingList<object>();

    //Dictionary<string, int> stats = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public frmTBAstatistics()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadMatchData();



        dynamic bluescores = new AdvancedList<object>();
        dynamic redscores = new BindingList<object>();

        foreach (dynamic match in matches)
        {
            int index = 0;
            foreach (object teamkey in match.alliances.blue.teams)
            {
                var team = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
                team.Add("key", match.alliances.blue.teams[index++]);
                team.Add("match", match.key);
                dynamic scorerecord = match.score_breakdown.blue;
                foreach(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty pi in scorerecord)
                {
                    team.Add(pi.Name, pi.Value);
                }
                teamstats.Add(team);
                bluescores.Add(scorerecord);
                redscores.Add(match.score_breakdown.red);
            }
        }

        dgvTBAstats.DataSource = teamstats;
        dgvTBAstats.Refresh();
    }

    private void LoadMatchData()
    {
        string matchpath = Files.appPath + Files.matchdata;

        if (File.Exists(matchpath))
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader matchfile = new System.IO.StreamReader(matchpath);
            string response = matchfile.ReadToEnd();
            matchfile.Close();

            matches = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);

        }
    }

    // End Class
}
```

I'm trying to define my own dynamic object to store summaries of the data retrieved but I can't figure out how to create a dynamic data model that I can bind to the DataGridView. I've tried a number of options, I assumed I needed to create a List populated with ExpandoOject, but I can't get that to bind and show the data. I have also tried a List of Dictionaries, but that hasn't really worked either.

Comment: do a simple google search on how to Bind a List<T> to a DataGridView. also you you could create match as a`new List<object>(){  };` and bind it that way.. or use / create a dynamic datatable lots of options in my opinion

Comment: I tried creating a list of objects, but since I don't know the members in advance, I created a list of dynamic objects, and it never shows the data.

Comment: After reading some more, I think I need to create  class that inherits Dynamic objects,  contains a Dictionary and overrides tryget tryset then create a list of that class.

Comment: I updated the code sample to better represent what I'm trying to do. While I was able to bind matches to the DataGridView and the data would populate, binding teamstats to the DataGridView doesn't throw an error, but the data never populates the table.